# How to stop a Stream using FirebaseAuth

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to grab data when the user signs in and it seems to constantly grab data around 5-8 times causing a bit of data strain on the back end. How would I achieve stopping this process once the snapshot has data?

Code:

```html
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream:  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Incorrect Username or Password!'));
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                
                Email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email.toString();
                CallDatabase();
                // return eDisclaimer();
                if (userRole == 'Education') {
                  return eDisclaimer();
                } else if (userRole == 'Packaging') {
                  return pDisclaimer();
                } else if (userRole == 'Welding') {
                  return wDisclaimer();
                };
                return LoginPage();
              } else {
                return LoginBody();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Future CallAPIs() async {
  await CustomerCall(userCustomer.toString(), ApiConstants.APIKEY);
  await OpenProjectCall(userCustomer.toString(), ApiConstants.APIKEY);
  await OpenTaskCall(userCustomer.toString(), ApiConstants.APIKEY);

  for (var project in projectlist) {
    await WIPRequestCall(project.job, userCustomer.toString(), ApiConstants.APIKEY);
  }

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), () async {
    await ProjectTimelineCall(userCustomer.toString(), ApiConstants.APIKEY);
  });

  await GetPortalFiles(ApiConstants.APIKEY);
}

Future CallDatabase() async{
   await ReadUserinDatabase(Email);
   userCustomer = userCustomer.replaceAll("(", "");
   userCustomer = userCustomer.replaceAll(")", "");
   await CallAPIs();
}
```

Once the snapshot has data it fires the CallDatabase method which is what seems to be called namouras times and I only need that method to be called once. Any help?

Comment: if you want just the first stream data use [Stream.first](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/first.html) property - the docs say: "The first element of this stream.

Stops listening to this stream after the first element has been received"

Comment: its not always the first one as it tries to log in and if it does work it tries again. This is why I want to stop once it has been seen to have data

Comment: so use `Stream.where` before calling `fitst` (or even better [Stream.firstWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/firstWhere.html) - more here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#process-stream-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is using `takeWhileInclusive` extension of [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) library

Add library to your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
rxdart: ^0.27.7
```

Import it

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
```

And use it

```
body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
stream:  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()
          .takeWhileInclusive((snapshot) => !snapshot.hasData),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
...
```

When `snapshot.hasData` will be true it will pass this event into your `builder` callback and stops listen the stream

Comment: When attempting to add .takeWhileInclusive((snapshot) => !snapshot the .hasData is showing as invalid

Comment: anything else you might have to help?

Comment: Show invalid what?